# Google voice indicator on incoming calls?

Tags: google-voice

I'd love to know when people call my cell phone through its original cellphone number and when people call me through my Google voice number.

Is there an app that can show me an indicator on the call screen?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe so.  You can set google voice to show your google number instead of the caller's, but then you don't know who is calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to tell if the call is coming from Google Voice unless you change your settings to show the google voice number, but then as Chris stated, you wont know who is calling. The reason, it is not the google voice app that handles the incoming call, you can actually receive google voice calls to your phone without even having the app installed. The google voice servers forward the call to your number(s), and based on your settings, they send either the callers info or your google voice number with the "caller ID" info.